# Wordpress How do I display tab content on click each sub tab name?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tabs, html-lists

I'm working on the WordPress custom page where I have added `jquery ul tabs`  in the custom template page.

1) Now how do I get the content in the tab panel after the click on the sub-tabs of the parent tab?

2) The `First` Tab should be open and active until click on the another `sub-tabs`?

3) Problem is that when I added `static content` tab showing `content` according to the `sub tab id` but jquery tab is not showing with `dynamic content`. No content is showing after the click on the `sub-tab` dynamically?

```
**Jquery**

    <script type="text/javascript">

     window.onload=function(){

     $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu a").click(function(){
        $(".video").each(function(){
            $(this).get(0).pause();
    })
    });
    //tabbing selection
    $(".menu li:eq(0)").addClass("active");
    $(".menu li").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');       
        }); 

    $(".tabs").click(function(){
        $(".subtabsinner").slideUp();
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');   
    });
    $(".subtabs").click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil("li.parent").slideToggle();
       $(this).removeClass('active');
       $(this).next().addClass('active');
    });

    });

    }

    </script>

     <div class="container">
   <div id="tabs" style="display: inline-flex;">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="leftmenu">
               <div class="menu">
                  <ul class='resourcepage'>
                     <?php 
                        $terms = get_terms('resourcecategories');
                        if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){

                        //parent tab name   
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        echo "<li class='parent subtabs tabsclose'><span>" . $term->name . "</span></li>";

                        $music_args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'resourceverticaltabs',
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'hierarchical' => false,
                        'resourcecategories' => $term->name
                        );

                           //sub tab name           
                        $musicians = get_posts($music_args);
                        foreach ($musicians as $musician) {
                        echo ' <li class="subtabsinner"><a href="#'.$musician->ID.'">'.$musician->post_title.'</a></li>';
                        }


                        }

                        }?>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col col-lg-8 col-md-8">
            //tab content
            <div class="rightmenu">
               <?php $musicians = get_posts($music_args);  foreach ($musicians as $musician) {?> 
               <div id="<?php echo $musician->ID ?>" style="border:2px solid red">
                  <?php echo $musician->the_content ?>
               </div>
               <?php } ?>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Static Content Link**
[Static Content](https://codepen.io/fdharsihexagon/pen/LgyLGZ)

Comment: Would be better if you could demonstrate your problem with a Stack snippet...

Comment: Problem is that function working on the static base not Dynamic

Comment: Any updated regarding my problem??